# How to connect/link two raspberry pies for video precessing?

Tags: pi-3, camera, opencv, webcam

i am fairly new to raspberry pi platform so this question may be too basic. I am working on a project where i need at least 2 camera modules for simultaneous video recording and processing and taking decisions based on that processed information .

Option 1: to use the official camera module and a USB webcam.

Option 2: to use 2 pies and 2 CSI cams .

I hope the 2nd option will be better. However i need to get and idea how to link the pies so that they can seamlessly communicate in between.

**THE PLATFORM I WILL BE WORKING ON IS OPENCV, PYTHON. I WILL BE USING PI3 B+**

Any suggestions,references will be of great help. Thank you.

Comment: There are more ways to link 2 computers (Pi or other) than you can poke a stick at. It all depends on what you want to do over the link. NOTE there are modules to allow you to attach 2 camera modules to a Pi.

Comment: @Milliways I had never heard of a module to attach two csi cameras to a rpi so I went and searched and found a few mentions of such things, but I couldn't find any product that one could purchase now, except for a rpi compute module which needs additional equipment to work.

Comment: @T.M. , I saw these modules . would cost me the same to buy a new raspberry pi altogether .

Comment: Yes the two pi, two camera option could work fine. Do the processing separately then report the results to one of the pi’s to make a decision based on the results.